# the_post_thumbnail in WordPress Loop wont work

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, templatetags

I'm new too this, and I can't get my loop to show the featured image from posts in WordPress.

I have tried with the_post_thumbnail and 
looked through https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails and other similar questions.

Hope you can help.

My loop looks like this now:

```
  <?php
  $query = new WP_Query(array(
      'posts_per_page'   => 4,
  ));

  while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
     <ul>
         <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
         <li><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></li>
         <li><?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
            } ?>
         </li>
     </ul>
  <?php endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

Comment: Is it showing the title and date corectly?

Comment: Hi Sofie, Could you confirmed if this loop is for custom post type or default WordPress post?

Comment: I have solved the problem thanks to @Jagir bahesh. (See the last answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here I am sending the code for you please check.

```
<?php

//Args
$myquery = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post', // Here you add your post type
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby'        => 'post_date', 
    'order'          => 'DESC'     
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php /* grab the url for the full size featured image */
    $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full'); ?>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></li>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>" /></li>
    </ul>
<?php }
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
// no posts found
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you have added featured image in post/page.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, it was the "featured image" I was missing. 
I had just added the image in post text itself, not the featured image box.

Comment: Shouldn't `$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );` be `$the_query = new WP_Query( $myquery );`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, maybe it works.

```
<?php
  $query = new WP_Query(array(
      'posts_per_page'   => 4,
  ));

  while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
     <ul>
         <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
         <li><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></li>
         <li><?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $image = get_the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
            } ?>
         </li>
     </ul>
  <?php endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` to your `functions.php` file in order for thumbnails to work

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the code. In such cases, you can use `get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id )` function and assign it to a variable. Then, you can `echo` it.

```
<?php
  $query = new WP_Query(array(
      'posts_per_page'   => 4,
  ));

  while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
     <ul>
         <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
         <li><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></li>
         <li><?php
            $thumbnail = '';
            if ( has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) ) {
                $thumbnail = the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail');
            }
            echo $thumbnail; ?>
         </li>
     </ul>
  <?php endwhile;
     wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

You can go through the detailed difference between the 2 functions at [How to get featured image in WordPress - the_post_thumbnail & get_the_post_thumbnail](https://webolute.com/blog/wordpress/wordpress-get-featured-image-the-post-thumbnail)

Comment: Suggested edit queue is full so I'm making a note here: You have contradicted yourself, `$thumbnail = the_post_thumbnail(...)` is not the correct usage.  

Should be `$thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail(...)`